# Select front end user record by feuser_id in typo3 AbstractAuthenticationService implementation

Tags: php, authentication, typo3, typo3-extensions

I am implementing a PIN Authentication service for Typo3 front-end users.

```php
<?php
/**
 * Copyright (C) 2022  HOMEINFO - Digitale Informationssysteme GmbH
 *
 * This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 */

namespace homeinfogmbh\pinauthentication\Service;

use Psr\Log\LoggerAwareTrait;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Authentication\AbstractAuthenticationService;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

use homeinfogmbh\pinauthentication\Domain\Repository\PINRepository;

final class AuthenticationService extends AbstractAuthenticationService
{
    use LoggerAwareTrait;

    final public function getUser()
    {
        if (!$this->isResponsible())
            return false;

        $pin = $this->login["pin"];

        if (strlen($pin) != 4)
            return false;

        $pin_repository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(PINRepository::class);
        $pin_entry = $pin_repository->findOneBy(array('pin' => $pin));  // TODO: Also respect page ID (how?)
        if (!$pin_entry)
            return false;

        return get_front_end_user_by_feuser_id($pin_entry->feuserId);
    }

    private function isResponsible(): bool
    {
        return GeneralUtility::_POST("login-provider") === "pinauthentication" && isset($this->login["pin"]);
    }
}
```

However, I cannot for the life of me find out, how I would implement `get_front_end_user_by_feuser_id()`. There seems to have been a [`FrontEndUser`](https://api.typo3.org/master/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_domain_1_1_model_1_1_frontend_user.html) model once, but it's marked as deprecated. I searched the official documentation for days now and also viewed some extensions' source code as a reference. But I could not find out, how I can select a front end user record by its `feuser_id` within an `AbstractAuthenticationService` implementation.
How can this be done?

Comment: Which TYPO3 version do you use? And how is it possible to mix all possible CGLs in that few lines? :)

Comment: It's 11.5.13. Regarding the code style. I'll clean that up, once stuff is working.

Comment: As the classes are deprecated, you should create an own FrontendUserRepository and FrontendUser. But as long as you're on v11 you can use the deprecated classes yet. They are removed in v12 earliest.

Comment: So, instantiiate the FrontendUserRepository and do a `findByUid()` to get the FrontendUser model based on the id.

Comment: Is the `feuser_id` equal to the record's `uid`?

Comment: I don't know what's in the record of your pin. :)